# Returning a JSON with a custom formatter. How to build the return statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Following [this tutorial](http://ciappara.com/blog/2017/09/27/how-to-exclude-json-properties-from-webapi-response-using-a-custom-contractresolver/) to try to exclude one of my properties from the `GET`'s JSON (but still be able to include it in my `POST`), and it seems fine until I get to the end where I have to return the following:

`return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, objectToReturn, jsonMediaTypeFormatter, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));`

It seems this statement is just not acceptable in .NET Core 2.1 which I am working with. There is apparently no signature for the `Content` method that takes 4 arguments of this type... I've looked at other tutorials but can't figure out what I would need to return to make this work.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: The tutorial might does not apply to Asp.net core application. Can you create a simple sample to explain more detail about your problem, and tell us what's the Get/Post's json looks like, and what data you want to get from the endpoint? Besides, I suggest you could refer [Custom formatters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and [Format response data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.1) in asp.net core 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

You have to not build any sort of `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` and just create a `JsonSerializerSettings` object then return a `JsonResult` ([documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.jsonresult.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_JsonResult__ctor_System_Object_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_))

`JsonResult` method signature:

```
public JsonResult (object value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings);
```

**Solution (tested)**

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new JsonExcludeFromResponseContractResolver() };
return new JsonResult(Program.Tasks, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

`Program.Tasks` is just the object you want to return in your `GET`.